How to vertically align individual inline latex equations compiled as svg files in paragraphs inside a html page?
I have individual inline latex equations compiled as svg files. I want to include them in paragraphs inside of a html page. I want to calculate vertical minus padding of each since the bottom of the svg equation coincide with the bottom of the html text. I want to vertically align as it were written as native text.
How can I achieve that?


<svg> are inline block elements, with the baseline always at the bottom of the layout box. You will have to compute the vertical positioning by hand. Your only chance would be if the library that compiles Latex to SVG provided extra information about the vertical structure.

@ccprog I use make4ht. I dont know if it is able to give me vertical padding on svg equations.
